# How to user IMAP to set the mail server

Tags: php, email

I have seen so many IMAP tutorials till now, but everywhere they only focus on how to retrieve messages from a mailing server. I could not understand anywhere how we can set up our own mailing server. I am planning to create a mailing application with my personal domain name but am not sure at all how I can go about setting it. Neither do I find anywhere how to set up our own personal server from where we can recieve e-mails.

Please share your knowledge on this area if you have any solutions to my query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with PHP whatsoever.

Google for a tutorial on how to set up a mail server, there are plenty.
Some examples would be *Dovecot* or *qmail*, (can be coupled with *postfix* for sending), but there are many idfferent products for that purpose.